# How do I collect filenames from a folder into a list?

Tags: perl, file

I am looking for a way to collect filenames into a list with Perl. For example, I go into a folder with a hundred different filenames ranging from text files to MP3, and I would like to put each and every filename in a list. How would I do that? I was looking everywhere and cannot seem to figure it out. I have gotten as far as using the `chdir` function but I can't seem to read the filenames and print them. Can anyone help?

Comment: Tofu, I have edited your post to replace a misleading word. If you do not agree, you can simply undo it.

Comment: thanks Daxim, that sounds better. Sorry for my english because it is not that good. I appreciate the help daxim. (^_^)

Answer (score 7):

One way is to open the current dir, and get all its contents, something like:

```
opendir(DIR, "yourDIR");
my @files = readdir(DIR);
```

obviously you can use `grep` like

```
my @files = grep {...} readdir(DIR);
```

to get specific types of files, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Look for the function [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
my @allfiles = glob '*.*';
my @musics = glob '*.mp3';
```